# How to specify the type of an array consisting of number and an array in typescript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following data structure  which I want to pass as a parameter into a function.

```
let structure = [6, [197,47,28,191,198,129,117,82,171]]
```

It's given that the first element is always a number and the second element an array of numbers. When I want to pass it to my function, my IDE suggests following as input types:

```
function myFunc(structure:(number | number[])[]) {
    ....
}
```

This leads to problems because it is not specific enough. I know the first element is always a number, but based on my type declaration it doesn't have to be.

How do you declare the type here properly in typescript?

Comment: Use a tuple: `[number, number[]]`

Comment: It has to be an array? Why not an object (e.g. `{ id : number; data : number[] }`)?

Comment: The array was given. Now I found out that's acutally a tuple type. I was able to sove it now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would specify it as a type

```
type MyStructure = [number,number[]] // give it a better name than MyStructure!
```

and use that for the function argument

```
function myFunc(structure:MyStructure) {
    ....
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiDKwBOBXAxsFToF4oG0A7FAWwCMIkAaY8y-AXQagHoWoBzASwDdovgUAIZQKwYJSiEhJaMAAWQwrATJ0mbAEIAsACg9egGYpCGLgHtlJEADETaABQBnNRiwQAXHESo32AJRQAN56UGFQegC+BrrWdqYO+ACMVPgATFQAzFQALEz+enH2iQBEQiWpGdl5DAWxtsXpWbm1QA) showing that it constrains the inputs to what you wanted

Answer (score 1):

```
function myFunc(structure: [number, number[]]) {
    ....
}
```

This is called a tuple type.